# Можно ли закольцевать LinkedList через LinkedListNode?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linked-list

Хотелось бы закольцевать список объектов так чтобы последний объект "ссылался" на первый элемент списка.
Можно ли такое сделать используя LinkedList и LinkedListNode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение найдено, можно написать расширение для `LinkedListNode`

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module ExtensionMethods

    <Extension>
    Public Function NextOrFirst(Of T)(ByVal current As LinkedListNode(Of T)) As LinkedListNode(Of T)
        Return If(Not current.Next Is Nothing, current.Next, current.List.First)
    End Function

    <Extension>
    Public Function PreviousOrLast(Of T)(ByVal current As LinkedListNode(Of T)) As LinkedListNode(Of T)
        Return If(Not current.Previous Is Nothing, current.Previous, current.List.Last)
    End Function


End Module
```